# Get specific values from multiple columns through pandas

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have 8 populations in VCF files:
[populations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B9gS.png)

I just want to extract AD and DP values from NEN_001,NEN_003    NEN_200,NEN_300 and LAB_004 columns. For example: first AD value is 23,2 and first DP value is 25.

I have made the function::

```
def extract_AD(info):
    AD= int((info.split(':')[1]).split(',')[0])
    return AD


pop1 = file[["FORMAT","NEN_001","NEN_003","NEN_200","NEN_300","LAB_004","LAB_300","LAB_400","LAB_500"]]

tst1pop1 = pd.DataFrame(pop1)

AD= tst1pop1["NEN_001"].apply(extract_AD)
```

but this function only works for single column as shown "NEN_001"

How can i extract my desired values from multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `applymap` method and slice all the columns you want.

```
cols_to_apply = ["NEN_001","NEN_003","NEN_200","NEN_300","LAB_004","LAB_300","LAB_400","LAB_500"]
AD= tst1pop1[cols_to_apply].applymap(extract_AD)
```